# Renaming dataframe without writing it to the global environment

Tags: r, string, dataframe, loops, data-wrangling

I have written a loop that stores data frames in a list and would like to use strings stored in a vector as their names. This way, I could refer to the dataframes stored in the list by their names without having to use indexes. I have searched the internet extensively to this issue but so far have not found any solution.

So far, I have used a workaround: I loop over a list of data frame names using read.csv(). In each iteration, I write the imported data frame to the global environment using assign() which allows me to me set a variable name. Using get() and a pattern matching approach, I then fetch data frames from the global environment and store them in a list.

This approach is quite cumbersome and only works when data frame names follow a shared pattern.

Preferably, I would like to rename data frames without having to use assign():

**Name of imported data frame 1  <- First element of vector containing the data frame names**

How could I achieve this?

I highly appreciate every help!

Answer (score 0):

My approach to this sort of problem is to use `lapply` to create the loop and then supply `names` for the elements of the resulting list.  This gives a simple, two line solution once the "create a data frame" function has been written.

For example, generating a random data.frame rather than reading a csv file for easy reproduction:

```
createDataFrame <- function(x) {
  data.frame(X=x, Y=rnorm(5))
}

beatles <- lapply(1:4, createDataFrame)
names(beatles) <- c("John", "Paul", "George", "Ringo")
beatles
$John
  X          Y
1 1 -1.1590175
2 1  0.6872888
3 1 -0.8868616
4 1 -0.3458603
5 1  1.1136297

$Paul
  X          Y
1 2 -0.3761409
2 2 -0.9059801
3 2 -0.7039736
4 2 -0.4490143
5 2  1.1337149

$George
  X          Y
1 3 -0.4804286
2 3  1.0573272
3 3 -1.9000426
4 3  0.8887967
5 3  0.6550380

$Ringo
  X          Y
1 4 -0.7539840
2 4 -0.3743590
3 4 -0.9748449
4 4 -1.1448570
5 4 -1.3277712

beatles$George
  X          Y
1 3 -0.4804286
2 3  1.0573272
3 3 -1.9000426
4 3  0.8887967
5 3  0.6550380
```

Make the obvious changes to `createDataFrame` for your actual use case.